# Appropriate SE site for following its mix of Webdev and programming

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a specific question , and it is now on hold after few seconds
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69644/barebone-easy-to-use-framework-for-not-such-basic-site
I know it is opinion based but I need community opinion so I can decide. 
Any advice where this kind of Q. can be asked on SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

> I know it is opinion based

Then it's not suitable for the Stack Exchange question and answer model.

By all means ask in a relevant chat room, but it might be a question best asked on another forum.

Comment: pity as SE site has really experienced users ...

Comment: @BojanT: So you want to hound them? One of the reasons the people who are here stay here is because your question is immediately rejected.

Comment: I hope you red a question , and there can be specific answer , but I got the point SE is not a site for users seeking this kind of stuff , neither is google nor forum that has 100 users, thanks anyway. Also http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/511/45182 as I understud if question is a bit specific like mine it should be OK

Comment: @BojanT: that is a meta post from a different site from 3 years ago. Any advice there certainly doesn't apply to Stack Overflow today. The Software Recs site *might* be the appropriate place for a sufficiently specific and detailed question.